# why does TensorFlow Object detection is grouping and drawing only one bounding box for several near by objects

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am doing an object detection on my own sample toy sets using tensorflow RCNN on my own dataset.

Sometimes when two toys are closed to each other, the tensor flow is bounding both boxes together. So instead of returning two bounding boxes, tensorflow returning one bigger bounding box.[Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wWIo.jpg)

(as in the attached image both red and blue cars have been bounded together)

Does anyone know what is the issue here and how to do individual bounding box identification for every single toy car?

Comment: First, are you sure that the objects are all separated in your training data ? If not, it's normal that it does that. If you never have this case (two objects very close), it's also normal, since it just sees some object pixels on the whole area where the toys are.

Comment: If you do have some of these in your training data, labeled separately, it becomes more tricky. You could try changing the NMS (non-maximal suppression) threshold to basically not use NMS, and see if the right bounding boxes are there or not (maybe they were just suppressed or fused into the big one). You can also try to compute the size of your feature map (last conv layer before the first stage of detection). If it is too small, then maybe the two toys are projected onto the same "feature pixel", which has the info of the location for 2 boxes but not the info that there are 2...